# pslegend with dot instead of rule

Tags: pstricks, legend

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-coil, pst-plot}


\begin{document}



\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Ox=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.1](0,0)(1.05,1.05){0.8\linewidth}{2.5in}%

    \pslegend[rt]{
    \red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt}  & Theoretical \\
    \blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & Numerical}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

I want the `\rule` next to "Numerical" to be a circle (dot) instead. I  tried with `\dot`, but that gave me an error. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pdf,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{llx=-1cm,lly=-5mm,urx=5mm,ury=5mm}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Dx=0.1,Dy=0.1](0,0)(1.05,1.05){0.8\linewidth}{2.5in}%
 \pslegend[rt]{%
   \makebox[2em][l]{\psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt](0,1ex)(2em,1ex)}  & Theoretical \\
   \makebox[2em][r]{\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](0,1ex){0.7ex}} & Numerical (with pstricks )\\
   \makebox[2em][r]{\pscircle*[linecolor=red](0,1ex){0.7ex}} & Numerical (with pict2e)
}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Is there any difference between putting the `pslegend` before `psgraph` and putting `pslegend` inside `psgraph`?

Answer (score 1):

Is that something like that you want? I give two ways, one that uses pstricks itself (you have to give the radius of the circle), the other that uses  `picte2e` (give its diameter).

```
\documentclass[pdf,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-coil, pst-plot}
```

\usepackage{pict2e} 
    \begin{document}

```
\begin{pspicture}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Ox=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.1](0,0)(1.05,1.05){0.8\linewidth}{2.5in}%
    \pslegend[rt]{%
    \red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt}  & Theoretical \\
    \raisebox{0.75ex}{\makebox[1.7em][r]{\pscircle*[linewidth = 1pt, linecolor = blue]{0.9mm}}} & Numerical (with pstricks )\\%
    \blue\raisebox{0.75ex}{\makebox[1.7em][r]{\circle*{1.8mm}}} & Numerical (with pict2e)
    }
\end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the circle completely filled?

Comment: Yes. It is as simple as adding a`*`at the \pscircle command. See my updated answer. Btw I removed the `blue` command, as I  bypass ordinary LaTeX commands.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to center it under the red line? (Sorry for asking more all the time)

Comment: Yes. Replace `[r]` with `[c]` as the optional argument of `\makebox`. Probably then the width of the box will have to be adjusted so that it be *exactly*  centred.